How to Delete A Node in AVL Tree (not by key but Node Itself)
The title is very self explanatory.
I'm curious about how to delete a Node in an AVL Tree.
The only condition is (that's also what makes other resources in the internet uselesss), the delete function should take the Node to delete directly as a parameter rather than the key of the Node and replacing the key.
I tried to use my functon that I created for a BST for this usecase. But unfortunately, it didn't work and I wasn't able to delete the root.
This is my BST code. I added balance tree at the return of the deleteRoot. But it still doesn't work.
public void delete(TreeNode x) {
        // Function to delete the Node (x) in the BST
        if (root != null) {  // If it's not an empty tree
            if (root == x) {  // If the Node is the root
                root = deleteRoot(root);  // Directly call the deleteRoot function
            } else {
                deleter(root, x);  // If it's not the root, pass to the deleter
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleter(TreeNode parent, TreeNode target) {
        // Recursive delete function to reach the Node we'd like to delete and call the deleteRoot method
        if (parent.getLeft() != null && target.getKey() < parent.getKey()) {  // If left is not empty and target Node is less than the current parent
            if (target.getKey() == parent.getLeft().getKey()) {  // If the left Node is our target
                parent.setLeft(deleteRoot(parent.getLeft()));  // Call the deleteRoot on the left child of the parent and set the new root to the left child of the parent
            } else {
                deleter(parent.getLeft(), target);  // If we don't have a match, proceed further in the BST
            }
        } else if (parent.getRight() != null && target.getKey() > parent.getKey()) {  // If right is not empty and target Node is more than the current parent
            if (target.getKey() == parent.getRight().getKey()) { // Applying the same procedures but for the right side
                parent.setRight(deleteRoot(parent.getRight()));
            } else {
                deleter(parent.getRight(), target);
            }
        }
    }

    private TreeNode deleteRoot(TreeNode x) {
        // Function to delete the Node in a BST that is the root of the tree
        if (x.getLeft() == null) {
            // If the Node we want to delete is a Node with only one right child (This case also catches Nodes with no child)
            TreeNode temp = x;  // Saving the Node in a temp variable
            x = x.getRight();  // Setting it into its right child
            temp.setRight(null);  // Disconnecting the Node we'd like to delete
            return x;
        } else if (x.getRight() == null) {
            // If the Node we want to delete is a Node with only one left child, we apply the same procedure as before but with the left side
            TreeNode temp = x;
            x = x.getLeft();
            temp.setLeft(null);
            return x;
        } else {
            // If the Node we want to delete is a Node with a child on both sides
            TreeNode temp = getSuccessor(x.getRight());  // Finding the successor
            delete(temp);  // Removing the successor from the tree
            temp.setRight(x.getRight());  // Inserting the successor into the place of the Node we'd like to delete
            temp.setLeft(x.getLeft());
            x.setLeft(null);  // Disconnecting the Node we'd like to delete
            x.setRight(null);
            return temp;
        }
    }

    private TreeNode getSuccessor(TreeNode x) {
        // Function to find the successor of a Node
        while (x.getLeft() != null) {  // While the left side is not null
            x = x.getLeft();
        }
        return x;
    }


"that's also what makes other resources in the internet useless": Not at all: as you have the node, you have the node's key, and then you can delete by key like all those resources are pointing out. What is the issue? "it didn't work": Please provide code to reproduce the problem, with code that builds a tree, takes a node and calls your delete method, demonstrating what goes wrong.

But the solution on the internet will copy the key of the Node to swap the nodes.
I kinde figured out the delete function myself but I'm stuck in finding the successor. Can you help me with this?

What is wrong with updating the key? It is the most efficient way...

I could not reproduce the problem you mention with your code. Please provide code to reproduce the problem, with code that builds a tree, takes a node and calls your delete method, demonstrating what goes wrong.
